# How to handle a dynamic WS URL in an iOS App

Tags: ios, web-services, url, redirect, dynamic

I am developing an iOS App which interacts with a remote WS.

Due to several reasons, I am not completely sure that the URL of the remove WS will be the same for ever, so I would like to implement an elegant strategy to automatically retrieve the current WS URL. Of course, this should be done in a transparent manner, without any interruption during the user activity or requiring to update the app.

The best idea I have for now is to get the current WS URL from a different "stable" URL, for instance www.mystabledomain.com/getwsurl

Do you guys have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to redirect to the correct URL from your stable URL instead of querying it every time?

Comment: @NumanTariq you are probably right! Actually I was looking for a solution which allowed me to avoid the redirection step, which might introduce additional communication delay and decrease the performance. By the way, maybe the simplest option is also the best one after all :-)

Comment: @NumanTariq I took your advice. If you write it down in an answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 1):

Could you just make your phone call urls on the stable service and have a script on the stable server  call the urls that are dynamic and then return the data to your phone?  That way your phone always talks to the same URL, and it could give you some flexibility later in how you talk to the WS.

something like

phone <--> stable server <--> dynamic WS

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion! By the way, would it not impact the application performance? Especially when the location of the stable server is very far from the server hosting the WS.

Comment: So the answers is it depends, do a traceroute from the stable box to the webservice and see what you get.  However, that being said having a middle man can give you a chance to do some interesting stuff to speed things up such as caching, condensing multiple calls into a single call, transforming XML to JSON.  I would highly recommend using JSON as your transport to the phone if at all possible XML is slow to parse on the device and is bandwidth intensive so if you can go with JSON it'll save you battery b/c you will need the radio to be on less and the cpu time needed to parse will be lower.